# Is there a ProtectedConfigurationProvider for .NET Core or Standard?

Tags: .net-core, .net-standard

Is there a ProtectedConfigurationProvider for .NET Core or Standard? Or if not, what is the equivalent for working with encrypted web.config files?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.protectedconfigurationprovider(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

It is called "System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" in .NET Standard.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager/

Answer (score 0):

ProtectedConfigurationProvider is available since .NET Core 2.0